# Can VIN number be used to steal cars?

Tags: car

I have been recently told that thieves these days are using your car VIN to steal cars by ordering your car key replica.

Is that correct, because my VIN and most of the new cars is visible on the windshield.

Any guide or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have components of your car sprayed with "data dot paint" so if a thief parts it
out via a wreckers said parts can be scanned and identified by the police motor vehicle
squad Virtually impossible to remove;one dot remaining is all that is required to identify
Not the answer you seek just a thought provoking option

Comment: It is not illegal to cover the VIN with tape, as far as I know. Anyone who really needs it has access to the inside of the car anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, people with access to the dealer computer network can do it, but they'll normally be tracked by login (in case they become a suspect).  They're supposed to verify ownership before supplying keys to others.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, but this need access to the constructor network and to his special hardware key encoder(..)

Comment: Care to elaborate?